# Cursor only shows as white plus symbol, unable to use shift and copy down

Tags: excel

Issue: In Excel the cursor is a White Plus symbol and despite a restart it's still doing it.

I'm now able to, as an example, drag formulas down, I normally holder shift and click or drag but the cursor is not changing and nothing appear to work.

Excel version - Office 365

I've checked my account is still valid as a first option.

Maybe I leant on a key combination?!

[image: Image similar to cursor]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Added something close as screenshot does not include cursors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File|Options|Advanced|Editing group

Ensure 'Enable fill handle and cell drag and drop' is checked.